# hot to do ng-show without an attribute

Tags: angularjs

I have bunch of places where I need to add ng-show to the element to hide it. Can it be done from one place in the code?

So instead of this template:

```
<tr my-row ng-show="$ctrl.model.toShow()"></tr>
```

It should be:

```
<tr my-row ></tr>
```

and then in the directive:

```
function myRow (){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'my-row.html',
        ..
        link = function(scope,el,attrs){
          scope.$watch('modle.toShow', function(){
                  //something here?
          })
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make these changes to the link function, and this adds an attribute `ng-show` to your my-row directive.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.directive('myRow', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'my-row.html',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var attr;
          element.attr('ng-show', true);
          var fn = $compile(element);
          return function(scope){
          fn(scope);
        };

         }
    };
})
```

[HEre is the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/37jFDAl09mFPXwhy7qzt?p=preview)

Comment: ADded a plunker,please check.